# 100% width div inside in another div, border it's not taken in account, but just in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html, width, border

chrome shows a strange behaviour with a 100% div (in another div). Both use the `box-size` mode.

The 100% widht div, doesn't take in account the border of the parent, in chrome, but it does in firefox.

```
 <div class="scheda_titolo">
 <div class="scheda_overlay_due"></div>
 Grand theft auto 5
 </div>
```

Here is a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8fEmt/10/):

Look it in firefox (works) then chrome (doesn't). or the image:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Consider using HTML Reset if you need all browsers to look alike

Comment: I tried two css normalizer. The problem is not there.

Comment: which two? You should pick the right one corresponding to DOCTYPE http://www.cssreset.com

Comment: this is my doctype:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> |---------------> witch one should i use @ShivanRaptor ? thx!

Comment: This one: Eric Meyer’s “Reset CSS” 2.0

Comment: mmm...it's not working... http://jsfiddle.net/8fEmt/12/ . Don't know what i'm doing wrong.... but it doesn't seam to fix the problem

Comment: the problem  shows up only in chrome, firefox works